# Adding data to datatable using object[] not working?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

The Add method for a DataTable contains an overload for adding data to a table using an object array.

I would like to have an array of arrays, which I can loop through and insert into the DataTable. The code below creates an array of size 4000 and puts an array of 4 "columns" into the 0th element of the outer array (ContiguousTradeMem).

However, when I debug the last line below all the data which was in testObject (and in the cache- ContiguousTradeMem[]) does not get copied over to the DataTable()???

```
//The "array" which we wish to insert into the DataTable
object[] testObject = new object[4];

//Inserts some test data
for (int m = 0; m < 4; m++)
{
    testObject[m] = "test";
}

//A test DataTable
DataTable test = new DataTable();
test.Columns.Add("Col1");
test.Columns.Add("Col2");
test.Columns.Add("Col3");
test.Columns.Add("Col4");

//Put the test "array" into the cache
ContiguousTradeMem[0] = testObject; //The data of testObject is fine here

//Write the cache element to the DataTable
test.Rows.Add(ContiguousTradeMem[0]); //The data is not fine in test.Rows
```

Comment: I think you are trying to add 4 rows(array) to 4 columned table.

Comment: you have 47 questions and only 66% accepted answers. Don't you like people helping you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the overload of [`DatarowCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56.aspx) takes a `param` array which is   similar to a list of paramaters. You can initialize and add the DataRow from your array in this way:

```
var row = test.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = (Object[])ContiguousTradeMem[0];
test.Rows.Add(row);
```

[params C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only problem is that I get a compiler error saying cannot implicitly convert object to object[]?

Comment: @user1107474: That's because the Cache stores objects and the compiler does not know that Cache[0] is an Array. So simply cast it to the appropriate type: `row.ItemArray = (Object[])ContiguousTradeMem[0];` (edited my answer)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to add 4 rows(array) to 4 columned table.

It should be logically:

```
DataRow newRow = test.NewRow();

newRow [0] = testObject[0];
newRow [1] = testObject[1];
newRow [2] = testObject[2];
newRow [4] = testObject[3];

test.Rows.Add(newRow );
```

You can also pass in an object array as well, like so:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Marks");
object[] o = { "Ravi", 500 };
dt.Rows.Add(o);
```

Or even:

```
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Ravi", 500 });
```

Comment: Hi, I wish to add multiple lots of "testObject" to the cache array, ContiguousTradeMem and then iterate through ContiguousTradeMem and add them all to the DataTable. is this still possible?

Answer (score 2):

test.Rows.Add adds existing DataRow object to your table. First you have to create new row, then fill it with your data, and after that - add it to your data table. Here is the code in VB, it is easy, so you will be able to translate it to C# :)

```
Dim t As New DataTable
Dim r As DataRow
r = t.NewRow()
r.ItemArray = testObject
t.Rows.Add(r)
```